# How to test array in AssertableJson in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-8, laravel-testing

In my Laravel project I want to test a JSON response what is acually a paginator result with `data` key. It's an array and it contains some elements. We don't know the amount exactly, because it's coming from a function.

My problem is if the pagination limit is 10 and I change the elements number over the pagination limit, for example 20, I still get back 10 elements only. But I want to test it too.

Now I have this code:

```php
$response
    ->assertSuccessful()
    ->assertJson(function (AssertableJson $json) use ($allElementsCount) {
        $json
            ->has('data')
            ->whereType('data', 'array')
            // here I want to test the count of 'data' array
            ->etc();
    });
```

How can I test an array count in a JSON response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$response->assertJsonCount(10, 'data');
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-json-count)

Answer (score 1):

I usually use

```
$reponse->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) => $json
    ->has('data', 10); // expect data has 10 items
    ->count('data', 10) // this also works, but I don't use this for no reason
    // and while at it, this is my way to make sure the order is correct
    ->where('data.0.id', $items[0]->id)
    ->where('data.1.id', $items[1]->id)
);
```

If only 1 item is expected

```
$reponse->assertJson(fn (AssertableJson $json) => $json
   // expect data has 1 item, and has these attributes
   ->has('data', 1, fn (AssertableJson $json) => $json
       ->where('id', $item->id)
       ->where('name', $item->name)
   )
);
```